# I don't want to require login for my app, but how do I keep their data separate?

Tags: swift, firebase

I don't want to have users login or anything, so how would I capture and sort their data to firebase?

Is there anyway to code and have the app recognize people by their device?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase provides an anonymous login feature. You can read more about it here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth

Also, if you choose to include a sign in feature later, you can convert the anonymous account into a permanent account while keeping their data.

Comment: Anonymous login is the way to go.